# この本は貸し出し中です　What is the meaning of "中" in this?

Tags: translation, meaning, suffixes

この本は貸し出し**中**です

I don't know if i should understand :

> Is it "not available", because it is in the "the process of~" 
>   being already loaned to somebody else?
>
> Or is it "**to be available for loan**"?

And  あの本は貸し出し**中**です is read like かしだし**ちゅう** or **なか**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the book is on loan (to someone) and therefore, it is not available.

「中」 is always read 「ちゅう」 for this meaning.